# Unable to access Handler in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi I am trying to change my cursor with the custom one where i got to know from here "www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/creating-a-.net-component-with-visual-basic.htm"

Its is throwing me an error **System.AccessVoilation.Exception** i basically understood by googling the exception but i don't know how to fix it.

So can any one help me...

below is my code and im getting the exception in the particular line in the program **lHandle = LoadCursor(0, curCursor.Handle)**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class AnimatedCursor_Ex
    Inherits SystemException


Private Declare Unicode Function LoadCursorFromFile Lib "user32.dll" Alias "LoadCursorFromFileW" (ByVal filename As String) As IntPtr
<DllImport("user32", EntryPoint:="SetCursor", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function SetCursor(ByVal hCursor As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Shared Function LoadCursor(
    ByVal hInstance As IntPtr,
    ByVal lpCursorName As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Shared curCursor As Cursor

Private Shared FileName As String



Public Shared Sub ShowCursor()

    Dim lHandle As String

    FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "dinosaur.ani")

    curCursor = CreateCursor(FileName)

    lHandle = LoadCursor(0, curCursor.Handle)



    SetCursor(lHandle)

End Sub

Private Shared Function CreateCursor(ByVal filename As String) As Cursor
    Dim hCursor As IntPtr
    Dim result As Cursor = Nothing

    Try
        hCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(filename)
        If Not IntPtr.Zero.Equals(hCursor) Then
            result = New Cursor(hCursor)
        Else
            'could not create cursor
            Throw New ApplicationException("Could not create cursor from file " & filename)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log exception
    End Try

        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Why `lHandle` is declared as `String`? I'm betting this is the cause for the exception...

Comment: Bozhidar is right. `lHandle` should be of type `IntPtr`, not `String`.